# How can I join two tables horizontally and match 2 different column names in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

I have two dataframes:

data1:

```
ID               DateTimeUTC
 A               12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
 A               12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM
 B               12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM
 B               12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM
 C               12/5/2019 11:31:02 PM
```

and data2:

```
 Message         DateTimeUTC
 A               12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
 A               12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM
 B               12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM
 B               12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM
```

I would like to have

```
ID              DateTimeUTC               Message              DateTimeUTC
A               12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM      A           12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
A               12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM      A           12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM
B               12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM      B           12/4/2019 11:31:00 PM
B               12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM      B           12/4/2019 11:31:01 PM
```

I wish to only show matching IDs and Messages. I have performed an inner join, but it is giving me duplicates, and it erases one of my column names.

```
 library('dplyr')
 inner_join(data1,  data2, by = c("ID" = "Message"))
```

Goal: Can someone show me how to do an rbind to get the above outcome?

```
##pseudo_code:
 rbind(data1,data2, order_by ID & Message)
```

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Moreover, Please consider formatting your question nicely. It just took me 5 minutes now to edit your question (I could put this time into helping you with this  problem instead)

Comment: for each data, for example data1, how eill you distinguish between the first row and the second row? eg. in the result, which row were combined?

Comment: @Onyambu I have edited this to show distinction. I will work on showing the reproducible result as well.

Comment: You get duplicates because every ID A gets matched with every Message A. There's no logic here to say that the first ID A should be matched with only the first Message A, and the second, and so on. Do you want to match by timestamps as well? Or what's the pattern?

Comment: By reproducible example, @M-- meant something which we can copy/paste into our R session. Something with `dput` or `data1 <- data.frame(.....`

Comment: Ok let me do this. I am away from my pc, I will do this soon

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idea of inner_join is correct, the problem is that instead of joining only on "ID" = "Message" you should also consider DateTimeUTC.
So it is joining on 2 conditions as follows;

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
    DateTimeUTC = c("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM", "12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM", "12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM", 
                    "12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM", "12/5/2019 11:31:02 PM"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    Message = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
    DateTimeUTC = c("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM", "12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM", 
                    "12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM", "12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c("ID" = "Message", "DateTimeUTC" = "DateTimeUTC"))

# ID           DateTimeUTC
# A 12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM
# A 12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM
# B 12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM
# B 12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind these two data sets together I would use `cbind`.

A caution though is is that this assumes that the data in each dataset is ordered correctly (i.e. the first 'A' in data1 actually goes with the first 'A' in data2).

```r
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- tibble(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
                    DateTimeUTC = c("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM",
                                    "12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM",
                                    "12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM",
                                    "12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM",
                                    "12/5/2019 11:31:02 PM"))

data2 <- tibble(Message = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                    DateTimeUTC = c("12/4/2019 11:30:30 PM",
                                    "12/4/2019 11:30:31 PM",
                                    "12/5/2019 11:31:00 PM",
                                    "12/5/2019 11:31:01 PM"))
# remove 'C' from the list
data1 <- data1 %>% filter(ID != "C")

# bind datasets togethers as per example above.
data_bind <- cbind(data1, data2)
```

Comment: see @Nareman's answer -- it is a method that can be applied more generally.  Only use my answer if it specifically fits your data.